How to post and redirect to an external website using ASP.NET MVC without using javascript/AJAX?
Im looking for something like this:
     public IActionResult ProcessPayment(CheckoutModel model)
     {            
    var paymentGateway = new PaymentGatewayService();
    var data = paymentGateway.PostPayment(paymentTransaction, selectedPaymentMethod);
    
return PostRedirectToExternalSite("url",data);
    }


Does this answer your question? Redirect to external URI from ASP.NET MVC controller

nope. thats a GET operation.

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0".
